# Remote host not showing files

Tags: intellij-idea, remote-host

I'm using intelliJ Idea 2016.1

I'm trying to connect to a remote host, the host is connected successfully, but I am unable to see any files on the remote host. It is also working fine with my other FTP connection.

Answer (score 1):

The Solution was pretty simple, I tried to connect it with fileZilla, it worked fine.So, I looked for the difference in the connection, fileZilla was using a passive mode.

I check passive mode in intellij-idea and it worked like a charm.